# Returning slices to a constant array

Tags: rust

I have a large constant array of floats (mesh coordinates) and would like to return various slices of it to use in OpenGL.  The following fails to compile:

```rust
const VERTICES: [f32; 10] = [
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 0.0];

pub fn vertex_coords() -> &'static [f32] {
  &VERTICES
}

pub fn texture_coords() -> &'static [f32] {
  &VERTICES[3..]
}
```

```
<anon>:8:4: 8:12 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
<anon>:8   &VERTICES
            ^~~~~~~~
note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
<anon>:7:42: 9:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 7:41
<anon>:7 pub fn vertex_coords() -> &'static [f32] {
<anon>:8   &VERTICES
<anon>:9 }
<anon>:12:4: 12:12 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
<anon>:12   &VERTICES[3..]
             ^~~~~~~~
note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
<anon>:11:43: 13:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 11:42
<anon>:11 pub fn texture_coords() -> &'static [f32] {
```

This also fails:

```rust
pub fn vertex_coords<'a>() -> &'a [f32] {
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an important distinction between a couple of concepts, *constants* and *statics*. These are distinct concepts in Rust. The detailed design of the distinctions from when it was introduced can be found in [RFC 246](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0246-const-vs-static.md).

The notable content:

> Therefore, taking the address of a constant actually creates a spot on the local stack -- they by definition have no significant address.

Given this understanding, it can be seen why taking a reference to a constant does not give a `'static` borrow—it is *not* a static reference, it is referring to something on the local stack.

There are two ways of dealing with this; one is to make the type a static reference (`&'static [f32; 10]` or `&'static [f32]`), whereby `VERTICES` can be of type `&'static [f32]` (it could also be `&'static [f32; 10]` if the constant has that type) and `&VERTICES[3..]` will be of type `&'static [f32]`. Because then the thing that has no significant address and is placed on the local stack is the `'static` reference—what it refers to *does* thus necessarily have a fixed address.

The other approach (and probably the preferred one) is to use `static` instead of `const`. That way you can take static references to it without let or hindrance.

And so:

```rust
static VERTICES: [f32; 10] = [
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0];

pub fn vertex_coords() -> &'static [f32] {
    &VERTICES
}

pub fn texture_coords() -> &'static [f32] {
    &VERTICES[3..]
}
```